# Adblocker that will only block invasive ads

Tags: web-browser, ad-blocker

I'm looking for an ad blocker, but I don't actually want to remove all ads. I want sites offering me free entertainment to receive advertisement revenue, and will tolerate basic ads to allow this to happen.

What I don't want is invasive ads.  Things that play sound or video or generate pop ups.  Anything that includes malware or tries to capture my CPU resources is out, and in general any ads that have a high CPU/memory footprint, to the point that they slow down my browser or computer.  I want to block these sort of ads, and *only* these sorts of ads.

I'd like suggestions for an addon for either major browser (Firefox or Chrome) which will do this. Alternatively I may instead need a suggestion for block lists I can load into an existing extension.

For example, my current favorite ad-blocker is **uBlock** in functionality and resource use, but even after I disable all the 'ad' level lists, blocking only the adware, CPU capture, and other annoying listed options, I still see it blocking ads that are I would consider non-invasive.  If I knew a good set of lists for uBlock, or another addon, which focused on only blocking the sort of ads I wish to avoid I would be happy to enable them only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before uBlock Origin, there was the original AdBlock Plus by Wladimir Palant. That extension remains available in Firefox (just search addons for it). It includes an option (enabled by default) to allow some non-intrusive ads.